# htaccess - read image from own server if external image not found

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I try some code examples from stackoverflow, but nothing seems to work.

So I have `<img src="http://external-url.com/image.png" />` and I want to show not-found.png from my server if http://external-url.com/image.png doesn't exists.

Can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(png|jpe?g|tiff|gif)$ /path/to/not-found.png [L,NC]
```

Change `/path/to/not-found.png` to your actual path of `not-found.png`.